# how to determine if an application was installed & started already

Tags: android

I want my application to know if it was installed & started already on the device. Currently, I store a unique user ID key in the shared preferences on the device. Restarting the application loads the user ID from the shared pref and hence, the application knows it was started previously. But after an uninstall and re-install, that shared preferences are gone byebye. Im aware I could write some file in external/internal storage of the device and those will not be removed on uninstall. But is there a more common technique to achieve my requirements? Other applications may read the contact's phone number use it server-sided to determine it, but I dont want to add such personal permissions to my app.

Comment: You will have to store user info data in server, if you don't want to garbage your phone, by writing info in some external file